# Android Adding List to Hashmap replacing old List

Tags: java, android, hashmap

## *calling the addOption function, again and again, replacing old values in Map

```
private void addOption() {

    counter=counter+1;

    List<AttributeValue> optionListInput = new ArrayList<>();    

    AttributeValue inputAtt;
    LinearLayout addOptionLaout=new LinearLayout(this);

    for (int ii=0;ii<addOptionListItem.size();ii++){
        inputAtt=addOptionListItem.get(ii);
        TextView labelText = new TextView(this);

        if (inputAtt.getInputType().equals("text") || inputAtt.getInputType().equals("textarea")) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            int id_for = View.generateViewId();
            editText.setTag(inputAtt.getAttributeCode());
            editText.setId(id_for);
            inputAtt.setViewId(id_for);                
            editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plain_box_white_round);
            editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            editText.setPadding(padding10, padding10, padding10, padding10);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            addOptionLaout.addView(editText);
        }  
        System.out.println("view Id: "+inputAtt.getViewId());
        optionListInput.add(inputAtt);
    }
    String mapCounter=counter+"";
    addOptionListMap.put(mapCounter,optionListInput);
}
```

Hashmap Old values are replaced by new view Id values .

Comment: What do you want!!! Can you please edit your question and make it more reasonable for others to understand

Comment: actually adding the list to the map is replacing old values in map

Comment: @SubodhAndroid what is demoList

Comment: @SubodhAndroid maybe you are using the same key to put the list .

Comment: @Krish I am entering the counter as a key which is surely incrementing for every call and It's not that it is showing only one record it is showing multiple records with same values(recent values)...

Comment: @SubodhAndroid Is there any other part of code is manipulating this map ?

Comment: Yes for deleting the records in the map I have used addOptionListMap=new Hashmap<>(); In other function

Comment: @SubodhAndroid but , it  doesnt change the old values of map. can you post some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone, I found Answer, as I am using java so it always sends the values by reference so the values which I modified get modified in parent Map so I created a new list and for each object, I inserted the parent list values in the object constructor of child list.